# How to avoid *.bbl file being reset automatically

Tags: bibliographies

I use TeXstudio, sometimes when I build the *.tex file, the related *.bbl file was reset to a empty document:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{\uppercase{}}

\end{thebibliography}
```

And there is a error message:

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{thebibliography}
```

My *.bbl file was manually created(copy from another project and manually modify the content), did I create the bibliography incorrectly?

My default compiler is PdfLaTeX, default bibliography tool is BibTeX.

Comment: Nothing deletes bbl by default so you must used have some option to "clean" the working directory of generated files. A simple way to avoid that would be to rename the file from `.bbl` to `.tex` and replace `\bibliography{yourfile}` by `\input{yourfile}`

Comment: Off-topic: The argument of `\begin{thebibliography}` should be a positive integer; the instruction `\uppercase{}` as the argument of `\begin{thebibliography}` seems suspect.

Comment: Thank for the comment. I was copied bbl file from other people and modified based on that file. I didn't notice that there is an error in the argument.

Comment: actually, to amend my initial comment, a clean directory option would have deleted the file not replaced it with a file with an empty environment. Most likely you have run bibtex on your main document when you have no bib file, only the edited bbl, this will give bibtex errors but could potentially make an empty bibliography. (I would still suggest renaming the file to .tex)

Comment: @Mico Strictly speaking the argument of `thebibliography` need not be an integer at all: It should hold the longest citation label (if citation labels are 'repeated' in the bibliography as is the case for numeric and alphabetic styles). In numeric styles the number of the last entry is a very good approximation for that (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449462/35864). But if you use alphabetic labels you would usually end up with an alphabetic label in the argument of `thebibliography`.

Comment: @moewe - Thanks! My earlier comment, about the argument of `\begin[thebibliography}` needing be a positive integer (generally, but not necessarily, given by the total number of bib entries), was indeed based on an assumption that the document employs numeric-style citation call-outs. It was good of you to point out that if the document employs alphabetic-style citation call-outs, the argument of `\begin[thebibliography}` should be the longest citation label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.bbl` file is *not* intended for manual editing.

BibTeX produces a printable bibliography in the `.bbl` file from the `.bib` file according to the style specified in `\bibliographystyle`. This `.bbl` file is regenerated on every BibTeX run. Thus the `.bbl` file is a temporary/auxiliary file like the `.aux` file.

LaTeX itself does not reset the `.bbl` file, but it is very possible that your editor either tries to clean up auxiliary/temporary files from time to time or tries to run BibTeX on your document, which may result in errors and eventually an empty `.bbl` if your document otherwise is not properly set up for BibTeX.

If you want to write your bibliography manually, don't use a `.bbl` file. Just write

```
\begin{thebibliography}{<longest label>}
\bibitem{<key>} <bibliography data>
\end{thebibliography}
```

directly  into your `.tex` document where you want your bibliography to appear (you may or may not have a `\bibliography{<some file name>}` there at the moment, remove the `\bibliography` instruction and any `\bibliographystyle` you may have in your document: they are only needed for BibTeX). That way you don't have to go via a `.bbl` file that might get overwritten by an external tool.

Most people, however, use BibTeX (or `biblatex`) to produce their bibliography. In that case you would create a `.bib` file of your resources and specify the `.bib` file with `\bibliography` and the bibliography style you would like to see your entries formatted in with `\bibliographystyle`. A nice answer showcasing the various options you have can be found at [How do I add "citations" at the end of the document as done here?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134180/35864). You may also be interested in https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-12.

---

Note that

```
\begin{thebibliography}{\uppercase{}}

\end{thebibliography}
```

looks a bit fishy: The mandatory argument to `thebibliography` should hold the largest citation label in your bibliography. The `\uppercase` does not appear to have any business there.